# Alt-tab switcher interrupting multiplayer games

Tags: windows, windows-10, gaming, alt-tab

I am having a problem with the alt-tab switcher popping up and interrupting games and it is driving me crazy! I will be seriously indebted to anyone who can help solve this for me.

Here's some additional info:

1) It's not that the window is fully minimizing, just that the window switcher is popping up, as if I had pressed and held alt-tab (it looks like the picture at the top of this article https://www.howtogeek.com/429223/master-windows-10s-alttab-switcher-with-these-tricks/, except that the switcher is overlaid over the game window rather than being overlaid over the desktop).  This still totally interrupts the game and is basically ruining it for me.

2) I have a Lenovo Y520 laptop and WIndows 10

3) The issue occurs when running graphically intense games (specifically I've had the issue with Mordhau and Call of Duty).  This is going to sound crazy, but it happens at specific times in the games, not randomly.  Specifically, it happens when I get hit or shot in the games.  (I know that sounds completely ridiculous but I swear it is true.)  This sounds even crazier, but it only happens when in multiplayer.  I can play the games single-player without issue.

4) I do not have the issue when running less graphically intense games like Civ 6.

5) Here are things I have already tried that have NOT fixed the issue:

A - Updating graphics driver

B - Using autohotkey to disable the alt-tab and windows buttons

C - Checking event logs to see if there are events that coincide with the alt-tab switcher showing up

D- Running the games in windowed, fullscreen, fullscreen borderless, or extended fullscreen modes

6) My system meets the requirements for these games, and I don't have frame rate issues when playing.

Comment: I don't see how this could be possible, and I've never ever heard of this happening, or anything remotely like it happening. If this is as replicable as you make it seem, I'd like to see a screencap of it. To be honest, the only thing that really makes sense is some sort of malware.

Comment: I'll work on getting a video.  It is almost like clockwork.

Comment: Okay, I uploaded a video of it happening at https://youtu.be/cPeb7hX53Fg.  The video is choppy and not full screen for some reason - the game is full screen and smooth.  In this case it totally minimized rather than popping up the alt-tab screen selector like I usually see.

Comment: Do you have Windows Defender enabled? Try running a scan of your PC to see if there's any malware it can detect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my mouse - a Logitech M720 (bluetooth).  I got a new mouse and the problem went away immediately.  Not sure whether it was some kind of incompatibility between my laptop and the mouse or if I had set the mouse up wrong somehow.